# Visual Studio region folding/unfolding

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, folding, regions

Regions are not the best thing that visual studio has come up with. I really hope there is a solution for this otherwise I will eventually stop using regions altogether.

Attached are two screenshots. I need to go from the 'FROM' state to the 'TO' state. Please note that you cannot see the actual code in the methods or properties. They are just headers. Is that possible? I am ready to waste tons of time to make this happen.

> From:

[image: From]

> To:

[image]

My outlining shortcuts are given below. I believe these are the standard ones.

```
Toggle Outlining Expansion : Ctrl + M, M
Toggle Outlining           : Ctrl + M, L
Stop Outlining             : Ctrl + M, P
Stop Hiding To Current     : Ctrl + M, Ctrl U
Collapse To Definitions    : Ctrl + M, O
```

I don't want all the code like with Ctrl + M, L. I just want definitions but with regions.

Comment: Take a look at [this extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0ca60d35-1e02-43b7-bf59-ac7deb9afbca), you can prevent regions from being collapsed, perhaps it will allow to collapse methods only with the usual shortcuts, like you need. But honestly, regions are a huge code smell and prevent the code from being readable from top to bottom like a book or an article.

Comment: *I really hope there is a solution for this otherwise I will eventually stop using regions altogether.* Just stop using them. I've found no compelling use for them unless I need to group things in a big class. And at that point, my problem is that I have a big class.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's all the motivation I need.

Comment: They are a useful feature nonetheless, alternatively  you could use bookmarks.

Comment: [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/featureSearch.asp/) has a VA Outline View that closely emulates your desired outline.